# Adding external .h files to NDK project in Windows

Tags: android, windows-7, android-ndk

I have added ndk plugin in Eclipse.

I have imported a NDK project in Eclipse.

But projects requires external .h file from the system, so I have added that folder where .h files files resides by

```
right click on project-> c/C++ General->Paths and symbols->then click on  
include and then click add and given path of that folder
```

also checked `all configurations` and `all languages`.

still when I build the project from `Command prompt` by moving to path where my project is , then `ndk-build` I am getting for .h file `no such file or directory` error.

How can I resolve this issue??

Please help...

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to documentation of `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` variable

Answer (score 0):

what you did to add the reference the external headers was only for eclipse, so it correctly resolves all the symbols and files references.

You also need to properly add a reference to these .h inside your ndk configuration files, ie inside `Android.mk`.

Use `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := path/to/headers` in your module, like in this sample Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.c
LOCAL_MODULE := mymodule
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../includes

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

If your .h files are part of a prebuilt module your own module depends on, use `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` inside the prebuilt module instead of `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` inside yours.